# set order to freeform pro field list type?

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a checkbox group field in Freeform Pro where the value list type is from a channel field.
Is it possible, using an attribute in the freeform tag to set the order (asc by title) of the items?

Thanks

Peter T

Answer (score 0):

Chalk this one up to operator error!
I had the solution all along!

Just use:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" status="open" orderby="title" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}
<li>
    <input id="freeform_field_{entry_id}" type="checkbox" value="{entry_id}" name="freeform_field[]" 
        {exp:query sql="select ff.entry_id as EID, ff.form_field_xxx  from apps_freeform_form_entries_xx as ff
        where ff.entry_id = '{segment_5}' AND ff.form_field_xxx LIKE '%{title}%'"}
        checked="checked"
        {/exp:query} >
        <label for="freeform_field_{entry_id}">{title}</label>
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```